# Parameter is missing or the value is empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am trying to access an "edit" link to edit an object, but I'm getting this error:

`Param is missing or the value is empty: preview`

Basically, I have 2 models that I linked through association:

`Game model`
`Review model`

I'm rendering reviews in the Game's show page. When I try to edit a review, it's saying I'm missing params or the value is empty in the Reviews controller.
The routes are also nested. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  root "games#index"

  resources :games do
    resources :news
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
    resources :previews, except: [:show, :index]
  end

  resources :platforms
  resources :genres

end
```

show.html.erb (Linked to Games controller)

```
<% if @news.last.created_at > preview.updated_at %>
    <p><%= link_to "edit", edit_game_preview_path(@game.id, preview.id) %></p>
<% end %>
    <p><%= link_to "delete", game_preview_path(@game.id, preview.id), method: :delete %></p>
<% end %>
```

Reviews partial (Form)

```
<%= form_for [@game, @previews.new] do |r| %>

    <h3 class="post_review">Preview this game</h3>

    <p><%= flash[:notice_submit] %></p>

    <p><%= r.text_field :title, placeholder: "Enter your tagline" %></p>

    <p><%= r.text_area :content, placeholder: "Enter your review here" %></p>

    <p><%= r.text_area :vote %></p>

    <p><%= r.hidden_field :game_id, value: @game.id %></p>

    <%= r.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Reviews controller

```
class PreviewsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_preview, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_game

  def new
    @preview = Preview.new
  end

  def create
    @preview = Preview.new(preview_params)
    @preview.user_id = current_user.id
    @preview.game_id = @game.id
    @preview.username = current_user.username

    if @preview.save
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:notice_submit] = "Thanks for you comment!"
    else
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:notice_submit] = "Either you've already voted, or you're not filling in all forms."
    end
  end

  def edit
    @preview.update(preview_params)
    redirect_to @game
  end

  def destroy
    @preview.destroy
    redirect_to @game
  end

  private

  def set_preview
    @preview = Preview.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_game
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def preview_params
    params.require(:preview).permit(:title, :content, :vote)
  end

end
```

Comment: Where is the `show` method in the controller?

Comment: hello! :) i didn't include a show because I didn't want a separate page to view each unique review. should i include it in the controller? not sure if there are any consequences for not including the show method.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in your `preview_params` you are requiring a `preview` object.

I think your controller logic for the `edit` action is invalid. For the `edit` action, you just need to `set_preview` and then render the edit template. The current logic in your `edit` action should go in an `update` action.

```
def edit

end

def update
    @preview.update(preview_params)
    redirect_to @game
end
```

Also the first line of your form should be:

`<%= form_for [@game, @preview] do |r| %>`

Comment: hey thanks for the input.-- if i don't put @preview.new, I get an error undefined method `to_key' for #<Preview::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x16829d30

Comment: nevermind, got it to work! it's really strange. For the Edit page, i can use `@game, @preview` but in the partial, i have to use `@game, @previews.new` -- can you explain why that's the case?